# Using VBA turn on a cell's double-underline

Tags: excel, vba

I've written (my first VBA) code to sum a column of numbers and draw a single, thin border around it.

I'd like to put a double-underline below the total cell.

Here's how I thought it would work.

```
rng.Parent.Cells(iRow, iCol).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlDouble
```

Comment: How does this "not work"? More code would be helpful, as well as a specific description of what isn't working.

Comment: `Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble` works fine for me, so maybe there's some other property which is set to a non-default value (eg like line color) which is causing your underline to not be visible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: This code successfully turns on the top border... rng.Parent.Cells(iRow, iCol).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = 1 '1=black 2=white 3=red 4=green

Comment: This is what I thought would work to turn on the double-bottom border... rng.Parent.Cells(iRow, iCol).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlDouble
rng.Parent.Cells(iRow, iCol).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = 1

Comment: ...but the bottom is just a thin, single line (like the rest of the borders around my numbers). I tried xlDash, xlDashDotDot, etc. but it always just shows a single line. There's something I don't get!

Comment: Can you post more of your code (in the question rather than as comments) - the snippets you have posted work.

Answer (score 1):

You can Record Macro (View > Macros), and view the generated code to see what might be missing.

```
With rng.Worksheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
```